# Understanding the Output of Vector and Matrix Multiplication in R

Tags: r, matrix, vector, multiplication, elementwise-operations

I am currently learning about matrix operations in R, and I encountered an output that I did not anticipate when multiplying a vector with a matrix. My understanding was that multiplication would be conducted element-wise, but the output suggests otherwise. The code I ran is as follows:

```r
num_matrix <- matrix(1:9, byrow = TRUE, nrow = 3)
new_matrix <- c(1,2,3) * num_matrix
print(new_matrix)

The output I got is:
[,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2    3
[2,]    8   10   12
[3,]   21   24   27
```

This looks like the vector c(1,2,3) has been multiplied with each column of num_matrix, which contradicts my initial expectation of a row-wise operation. Could someone explain why the multiplication behaves like this and not row-wise as I expected?

Additionally, if I want to multiply a vector with each row of a matrix, rather than with each column, how can I achieve that in R?

Thank you for any assistance!

Comment: `*` is not matrix multiplication, `%*%` is

Comment: @r2evans I'm not sure why this question got closed for being 'resolved as less likely to help future readers', it's not about matrix multiplication at all? It's rather about the order in which vectorized element-wise multiplication happens on matrices, as correctly addressed by both answers given. Arguably similar questions were asked/answered before but the ones here aren't wrong, nor is the question a typo/irreproducible.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure about it. Admittedly I posted my comment above while not at my computer, so I missed your point that you were not trying to do linear-algrebra-matrix-multiplication, my apologies for misreading that. I did not vote to close it. Do you still have questions not resolved by the two answers?

Answer (score 4):

Matrices in R are vectors in column-major order. You can transpose your matrix to have elements recycled along columns that were previously rows, and then transpose back:

```r
(want_matrix <- t(t(num_matrix) * 1:3))
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3]
#> [1,]    1    4    9
#> [2,]    4   10   18
#> [3,]    7   16   27
```

For kicks, here's a few other methods and their benchmarks. Note that treating this as a *matrix* multiplication will be fastest when the input is small, but doesn't scale well -- transposing is more consistent.

**Edit**: the method of @ThomasIsCoding (`f5` below) turns out to be faster throughout!

```r
f1 <- \(m, v) t(t(m) * v)
f2 <- \(m, v) t(apply(m, 1, \(r) r*v))
f3 <- \(m, v) sweep(m, 2, v, `*`)
f4 <- \(m, v) m %*% diag(v)
f5 <- \(m, v) m * v[col(m)]

bench <- function(n, ...) {
  m <- matrix(rnorm(n*n), ncol=n)
  v <- runif(n)

  microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
    transpose=f1(m,v),
    apply=f2(m,v),
    sweep=f3(m,v),
    `%*%`=f4(m,v),
    col=f5(m,v),
    ...,
    check = "equivalent"
  )
}

bench(10)
#> Unit: microseconds
#>       expr   min     lq    mean median     uq   max
#>  transpose  30.4  33.40  34.919   34.1  35.00  53.1
#>      apply 121.5 124.60 128.871  125.6 128.60 188.1
#>      sweep  94.1  97.90 107.103   99.5 102.80 275.0
#>        %*%  13.1  14.70  15.272   15.1  15.45  29.9
#>        col  10.9  12.05  12.548   12.5  12.90  21.0

bench(100)
#> Unit: microseconds
#>       expr   min     lq    mean median     uq   max
#>  transpose  92.0  95.50 101.730  96.90 102.45 157.6
#>      apply 392.3 398.05 418.783 403.60 427.35 566.8
#>      sweep 154.4 159.40 171.652 161.20 168.00 390.7
#>        %*% 495.4 497.20 514.902 498.00 524.75 907.0
#>        col  60.7  62.15  65.206  62.95  65.90 117.3
```

Comment: interesting benchmarking, +1!

Answer (score 4):

You can try `col`+ `*` like below and benchmark

```
microbenchmark(
    f1 = num_matrix * (1:3)[col(num_matrix)],
    f2 = num_matrix %*% diag(1:3),
    unit = "relative",
    check = "equivalent"
)
```

and you will see

```
Unit: relative
 expr      min       lq    mean median       uq       max neval
   f1 1.000000 1.000000 1.00000 1.0000 1.000000 1.0000000   100
   f2 1.553829 1.498501 1.30164 1.4995 1.454133 0.5962642   100
```